# How to stop Forced browsing ? - Saving information from being compromised by url change

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

In some webpages or views, I have information displayed in table. Column values are rendered as links.

Problems:
1. When I hover over the link, it's URL is visible at the bottom of browser.
2. When I click on link, I show information for the resource requested in URL. (www.someurl.com/Employee/67 gives me information of employee with id = 67). Now, this URL is displayed in browser. If you change URL to www.someurl.com/Employee/88, it shows information of employee with id = 88 though the logged in user is not supposed to see information for employee id 88

These are serious security breaches.

I am thinking of following as possible solutions:

1. URL masking at application level
2. Base64 encoding of URL to shorten and obfuscate it, so that users can't just throw values in the URL.
3. @Html.AntiForgeryToken() and ValidateAntiForgeryTokenValidation mechanism

Is there better and more secure approach other than above to solve this issue?

Regards,

Suraj

Comment: None of the above. Before delivering the page `www.example.com/Employee/88` the server needs to verify the the current user may view that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description you have mentioned it seems that you are talking about a security vulnerability which is popularly know as [Insecure Direct Object Reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References).

To mitigate this kind of issue, you should Check for the user whether he have access to particular resource or not. Base64 encoding the URL will not work in this.

I would to recommend you to go through [this blog post: OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 4: Insecure direct object reference](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/09/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-4.html), which is written by Troy Hunt.

I hope this will help you to secure your apps.

Comment: Yes. Seems like to most secure solution for insecure direct object references.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to fix this is to enforce role-level or item-level authorisation for each of your actions.

Your assumptions must be:

1. That every url to your site is known, as they all follow a predictable template
2. That obfuscation does not matter - at some point a post will send the id, obfuscated, or substituted or not, so it is possible to predict any id if you know the obfuscation system (which in itself is predictable).

Therefore a malicious user could simply iterate through every id (from -2147483647 to 2147483648) using your url for your actions (e.g. mysite.com/user/delete/id). Using a Guid makes no difference, it just makes the attack space slightly bigger.

Inside your actions you therefore need to check that:

1. the user is authenticated (typically using the `AuthorizeAttribute`)
2. the user is authorised to access the exact object they are submitting a request for. This is true of read/update/create/delete actions.

You can do this at a granular level using roles (also with the `AuthorizeAttribute`, so that only Administrator role members can delete a user), or at an item-level by implementing your own permissions system (for example, you store a table listing the users who are allowed to create/read/update the profile of another user).